# error while building opencv 2.4.5 application with eclipse and ubuntu 13.04

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv, eclipse-cdt

this is maybe a noob question but I've been stuck for a while and I appreciate any help...

I have been able to install opencv and run a sample application using the terminal without any problems however I want to use eclipse to manage my project easily...

I have followed the instructions given by the opencv tutorial in this [link]
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html

I followed everything and i still get the following errors

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_calib3d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_contrib
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_core
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_features2d
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_flann
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_gpu
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_highgui
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_imgproc
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_legacy
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ml
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_nonfree
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_objdetect
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_photo
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_stitching
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_superres
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_ts
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_video
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -llibopencv_videostab
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Test_OpenCV01] Error 1
```

the only differences I was able to find between my steps and the tutorial is:
when i run the command :

```
pkg-config --libs opencv
```

this is my output

```
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_calib3d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_contrib.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_features2d.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_flann.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_gpu.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_highgui.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_imgproc.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_legacy.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ml.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_nonfree.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_objdetect.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_photo.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_stitching.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_superres.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_ts.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_video.so /usr/local/lib/libopencv_videostab.so
```

so the library names are a bit different so I use the names that I have.

the command line that was executed automaticly from eclipse is

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -o "Test_OpenCV01"  ./src/main.o   -llibopencv_calib3d -llibopencv_contrib -llibopencv_core  -llibopencv_features2d  -llibopencv_flann -llibopencv_gpu -llibopencv_highgui -llibopencv_imgproc -llibopencv_legacy -llibopencv_ml -llibopencv_nonfree -llibopencv_objdetect -llibopencv_photo -llibopencv_stitching -llibopencv_superres -llibopencv_ts -llibopencv_video -llibopencv_videostab
```

it clearly specifies that the library path is /usr/local/lib/ which is where the shared libraries are at however in the error it says that it can't find the lib files in /usr/bin/ld

p.s. 
I have tried both

1)Configuring OpenCV for using shared libraries:

> sudo gedit /etc/ld.so.conf.d/opencv.conf

and adding the following line at the end of the file

> /usr/local/lib the running sudo ldconfig after saving.

2)run the command

> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib

I also added

> PKG_CONFIG_PATH=$PKG_CONFIG_PATH:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
>   export PKG_CONFIG_PATH

to the end of the /etc/bash.bashrc file.

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Answer (score 1):

Your linking step is specifying the libraries incorrectly.  If the library is `libfoo.so`, then you need to say `-lfoo`.

Replace

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -o "Test_OpenCV01"  ./src/main.o   -llibopencv_calib3d -llibopencv_contrib -llibopencv_core  -llibopencv_features2d  -llibopencv_flann -llibopencv_gpu -llibopencv_highgui -llibopencv_imgproc -llibopencv_legacy -llibopencv_ml -llibopencv_nonfree -llibopencv_objdetect -llibopencv_photo -llibopencv_stitching -llibopencv_superres -llibopencv_ts -llibopencv_video -llibopencv_videostab
```

with

```
g++ -L/usr/local/lib/ -o "Test_OpenCV01"  ./src/main.o   -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core  -lopencv_features2d  -lopencv_flann -lopencv_gpu -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_nonfree -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab
```

You can read more about linking options [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html).

Answer (score 0):

Even though the file names are like liblibopencv_core.so under /usr/local/lib folder, in GCC C++ linker libraries just mention **opencv_core**. Do the same for other files you are adding in library.